# Release cl::Buffer and memory leakage on device

Tags: memory-leaks, buffer, opencl

we know that in openCL by using `cl::CreateBuffer()` we can create buffer in device, which allocate memory there. But my question is whether the buffer would be free after terminating the program or there is a function we should use to free the memory to prevent memory leakage on device.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor for the `cl::Buffer` object returned by `cl::CreateBuffer()` will release the buffer, which will also free any memory allocated on-device. This is the main mechanism you should be relying upon.

Process death for any reason (crash, clean exit) even with resources allocated will also destroy the process's context handle in the device driver, which will cause the driver to perform the cleanup.

Of course, bugs at any level of the stack could prevent this from happening correctly in all cases, but in general, once your process dies, everything should be reset.